# Origin of $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, reference-request

In what paper, article or book was the notion of an $\sigma$-algebra first defined or mentioned? Or at least how far could this concept traced back?

Comment: Still on topic here, but [hsm.se] would be a better place.

Comment: I would assume in Lebesgue's thesis introducing Lebesgue integration...

Comment: Maybe this link will help? http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathword.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this study by Jean-Philippe Villeneuve (in French): http://culturemath.ens.fr/histoire%20des%20maths/htm/villeneuve2009/theories-de-la-mesure.html

the essential property of sigma-additivity that is used to define sigma-algebra was first used both by Émile Borel in 1898 for his work on the theory of functions in which there is a chapter on the measure theory:

- Émile Borel, 1898, "Leçons sur la théorie des fonctions : principes de la théorie des ensembles en vue des applications à la théorie des fonctions"

and by Henri Lebesgue in one or both of his works on integration in 1902 and 1904:

- Henri Lebesgue, 1902, "Intégrale, longueur, aire"
- Henri Lebesgue, 1904, "Leçons sur l'intégration et la recherche des fonctions primitives"

Since I cannot access these text I cannot say whether the term sigma-algebra was then already used.

Comment: Thanks for the references! Unfortunately I do not understand French, so if anybody knows translations I would be glad!